# sbt project read file

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a Scala project built with SBT.

This is my project structure:

```
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── java
│   │   ├── resources
│   │   │   └── code.txt
│   │   └── scala
│   │       └── test
│   │           ├── parser.scala
│   │           └── temp.scala
│   │           
│   └── test
│       ├── java
│       ├── resources
│       └── scala
```

I want to read the content of `/src/main/resources/code.txt` in `/src/main/scala/test/parser.scala`. How should I write code in parser.scala or I should do more setting in build.sbt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just getResource should be good

```
val resource = this.getClass.getResource("/code.txt")
```